# Returning Http Status Code to Apache from PHP?

Tags: php, apache, http, http-status-codes, errordocument

On my local development machine, I downloaded PDT + Zend Server, which included Apache 2.2.16 and PHP 5.3.5, running on Windows 7. On my local site, I included a .htaccess that includes ErrorDocuments for 404, 403, and 500. In my PHP, I use header("Http/1.0 404 Not Found") when the user requests a document that doesn't exist. On my local server, everything works great. My custom ErrorDocument appears and I'm happy.

I upload the everything to my shared host running Apache 2.2.38 and PHP 5.3.8 on a Linux server, and suddenly the ErrorDocuments only work if they don't come from PHP.

Is there some setting in PHP.ini or httpd.conf or .htaccess that allows Apace to see the error codes from PHP, which makes my dev server work correctly, but not my shared host?

In researching this, all I ever saw was "Apache doesn't see the status code once it passes off to PHP." In such a case, why does my dev server work right?

**Edit**

For clarity, here's the .htaccess:

```
# Use PHP 5.3
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddHandler application/x-hg-php53 .php 

#Deny Include Files
<Files *.inc>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</files>

#Provide custom error documents
ErrorDocument 404 /Errors/Http404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /Errors/Http403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /Errors/Http500.php
```

The .htaccess **works** because if the user navigates to myhost.com/jdkslfjdls the user receives the content of Errors/Http404.php.

However, if the user navigates to myhost.com/images/GetImage.php?Id=5 (when there is no image #5) the user receives no content.

If they navigate to (Internal IP Address)/images/GetImage.php?Id=5, the user receives the content of Errors/Http404.php.

A similar problem occurs if the user tries to access GetImage.php?Id=6 (when there is an image #6 but they don't have permission). On the shared server, they get a blank page or the browser's 403 error. On my dev server, they get my actual custom 403 error page.

Again, 403 error document works on the shared server if I try to access a .inc file.

Comment: Where is the custom error document located? It needs to be reachable by the linux server, so if its only on your windows server then thats why its not showing it

Comment: It shows when I try to navigate to a non-existing document, for example http://myhost.com/hfjdshfkdsh. It only fails when I use header from php.

Comment: where are you putting the header("Http/1.0 404 Not Found")? In a document that exists but you want it to throw a 404 code?

Comment: Right, if the user accesses GetImage.php?Id=5 and ID 5 doesn't exist in the database, it returns a 404. If it does exist but the currently logged in user doesn't have permission, it shows a 403. On my local server, the user receives the ErrorDocument pages from .htaccess. On the shared server, they don't get any content.

Comment: xnay that last comment, have you seen this discussion `http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3205630.htm` looks like its not possible? But you say it WAS working on your windows setup?

Comment: Right, that's one of the pages that came up in my research. I'm mystified as to why that page says it shouldn't work when it clearly DOES work on my windows server.

Comment: I just tested it on my linux apache server and it just shows a blank page also. My error document settings are directly in the sites configuration not .htaccess files (since I own the server).  I also changed my AlowOverride to All from None with no change in the page

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your .htaccess file is used on the server? Sometimes the hosting company does not allow the global apache settings to be overwritten by the local .htaccess files.

If you however have access to your virtualhost configuration than you may want to look at the following directive

```
AllowOverride All
```

If instead you find

```
AllowOverride None
```

try to change as above.

Comment: The .htaccess is in use because if I navigate to myhost.com/fkjdshfkds I get the correct, custom 404 document. It's only an issue when I try to use header("Http/1.0 404 Not Found") or other status code from PHP, which does work on my windows server but not on the shared host.

Comment: can you do a fast hack to redirect from php to a nonexistent page and get the document ? :P I know this does not offer a solution, but if you really need it up and running it may help you for a while.

Comment: My current hack is to fpassthru an error image that says "You need permission" or "Image not found". But that is a good idea to use a header redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have

```
AllowOverride ALL
```

in your apache.conf under the Directory directive inside the VirtualHost corresponding to your website

Anyway, that may be one possible cause, the other may be to check whether or not you have enabled mod_rewrite

On ubuntu or debian based systems, you'd simply link or copy the mod_rewrite.load from /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_rewrite.load to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_rewrite.load

Rewrite should have nothing to do though, but I've seen cases where your .htaccess directives may require mod_rewrite

So check for those things in apache conf files.
If nothing happens contact me @ phpcip@gmail.com

Hope it works.

Comment: I've now tried it with "RewriteEngine On", but there's no change.